# Matlab algorithm for obtain the original numbers of a sum of random numbers

Tags: matlab

Have 8 people in a room seated in a round table and each of them chose a random number and sum with the number of the people in his right and left side. The results are bring to you in order where people was in the table, how you can obtain the original number what each one chose?

```
Lower_rand_limit = 1;
Upper_rand_Limit = 100;
Number_of_colums = 8;
Number_of_lines = 1;
Random_matrix = randi([Lower_rand_limit Upper_rand_Limit], Number_of_lines, Number_of_colums)
Sum_matrix = zeros(Number_of_lines, Number_of_colums);

for i = 1:Number_of_colums
    if i == 1
        Sum_matrix(Number_of_lines, i) = Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, Number_of_colums) + Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, i) + Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, i + 1);
    elseif i == Number_of_colums
        Sum_matrix(Number_of_lines, i) = Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, Number_of_colums- 1) + Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, Number_of_colums) + Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, 1);
    else
        Sum_matrix(Number_of_lines, i) = Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, i - 1) + Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, i) + Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, i + 1);
    end
end

Sum_matrix
```

Now only whit the Sum_matrix how can i obtain the original Randon_matrix?

---

Thanks to the answear of nikaltipar it's working now, for who want see the entire code he it's here:

```
Lower_rand_limit = 1;
Upper_rand_Limit = 100;
Number_of_colums = 1;
Number_of_lines = 8;
Random_matrix = randi([Lower_rand_limit Upper_rand_Limit], Number_of_lines, Number_of_colums)
Sum_matrix = zeros(Number_of_lines, Number_of_colums);

 for i = 1:Number_of_lines
     if i == 1
         Sum_matrix(i, 1) = Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, 1) + Random_matrix(i, 1) + Random_matrix(i + 1, 1);
     elseif i == Number_of_lines
         Sum_matrix(i, 1) = Random_matrix(Number_of_lines - 1, 1) + Random_matrix(Number_of_lines, 1) + Random_matrix(1, 1);
     else
         Sum_matrix(i, 1) = Random_matrix(i - 1, 1) + Random_matrix(i, 1) + Random_matrix(i + 1, 1);
     end
 end

Sum_matrix

A = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
     1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1;
     1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1];

Result_matrix = A\Sum_matrix;

Result_matrix
```

Comment: You ask this as a Matlab question which must mean that you would know how to solve it on paper and only struggle with the implementation. Can you show us your idea how to approach the problem and where you are stuck particularly? As a hint, think of linear systems of equations.

Comment: Sorry if it dont was clear. I dont know how to solve it on paper, and this is the problem, if you can tell me how to solve this on paper i will know how to implement in matlab. In order to give a better understand i will update the post with of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
function [ x ] = original_numbers( b )

    A = [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1;
     1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0;
     0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0;
     0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0;
     0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0;
     0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1;
     1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1];
    x = A\b;


end
```

You provide `b` which is a column vector with the sums as you have described, and the output `x` consists of the original number the people in the table came up with.

e.g

```
b = [1;
      2;
      3;
      4;
      5;
      6;
      7;
      8];

original_numbers(b)

ans =

     3
    -2
     1
     4
    -1
     2
     5
     0
```